# How to store/add list elements in Array-list in the below format?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections

How to store/add list elements in Array-list in the below format?

```
x.get(0)->[1,2,3,4],
x.get(1)->([5,6,7,8],
x.get(2)->[9,10,11,12],
x.get(3)->[13,14,15,16]
```

I'm getting a sequence of numbers and want to separate them with a list.
When i use x.add(), that is adding all elements to a single list in sequence order.

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: You want a list of lists. Basically, List<Integer> A = (1,2,3,4), List<Integer> B = (5,6,7,8), etc. Then you have List<List<Integer>> Z = (A, B, ...) where A and B refer to the above lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this an arraylist of arraylists:

```
ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> arrayList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();

ArrayList<Integer> tempArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

tempArrayList.add(1);
tempArrayList.add(2);
tempArrayList.add(3);
tempArrayList.add(4);
arrayList.add(tempArrayList);

System.out.println(arrayList.get(0).get(0));
System.out.println(arrayList.get(0).get(1));

tempArrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

tempArrayList.add(5);
tempArrayList.add(6);
tempArrayList.add(7);
tempArrayList.add(8);
arrayList.add(tempArrayList);

System.out.println(arrayList.get(1).get(0));
System.out.println(arrayList.get(1).get(1));

etc...
```

If you have a fixed amount of numbers for each list you could do an `ArrayList` of `int[]` arrays...

Comment: Super...Worked for me with little change System.out.println(arrayList.get(0)) is giving full list

Answer (score 1):

By this way you can add list(ArrayList) into `ArrayList`.

```
//Adding `ArrayList` into `ArrayList`

ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> list = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

//adding element to innerlist 
innerList.add(10);
innerList.add(20);
...

//adding innerList into list

list.add(innerList);
```

---

if you are getting a sequence of number as : 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16.

Then below code can help you in preparing a list and adding into `ArrayList`.

```
public  ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> mainlist = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();
public void prepareList() {
        ArrayList<Integer> innerList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 1; i <= 16; i++) {
            innerList.add(i);
            if (i % 4 == 0) {
                mainlist.add(innerList);
                innerList = new ArrayList();
            }
        }
    }
```